# Obtain DTD information from XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, sax, dtd

I'm trying to extract the DTD information from an XML document using Python and preferably the standard library. At first glance, it seems `xml.sax.handler.DTDHandler` is the way to go, so I wrote the following example code to extract the DTD of a trivial DocBook v4 document:

```py
import xml.sax
from contextlib import closing

XML_CODE = '''<!DOCTYPE example PUBLIC 
    "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN"
    "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd">
<example><title>Hello World in Python</title>
<programlisting>
print('Hello World!')
</programlisting>
</example>'''

class DTDPrinter(xml.sax.handler.DTDHandler):
    def notationDecl(self, name, publicId, systemId):
        print('name={}, publicId={}'.format(name, publicId))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with closing(xml.sax.make_parser()) as parser:
        parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_external_pes, False)
        parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_validation, False)
        parser.setDTDHandler(DTDPrinter())
        print('---------- before feed')
        parser.feed(XML_CODE)
        print('---------- after feed')
```

My expectation was that when running this code with Python 3.5 the output would be something like:

```
---------- before feed
name=example, publicId=-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN
---------- after feed
```

Instead I get an output with DTD's seemingly related to various image formats but not the one specified in the document:

```
---------- before feed
name=BMP, publicId=+//ISBN 0-7923-9432-1::Graphic Notation//NOTATION Microsoft Windows bitmap//EN
name=CGM-CHAR, publicId=ISO 8632/2//NOTATION Character encoding//EN
name=CGM-BINARY, publicId=ISO 8632/3//NOTATION Binary encoding//EN
...
name=WMF, publicId=+//ISBN 0-7923-9432-1::Graphic Notation//NOTATION Microsoft Windows Metafile//EN
name=WPG, publicId=None
name=linespecific, publicId=None
---------- after feed
```

Although maybe the last entry with the name `linespecific` might refer to the document DTD in a crippled way?

I also noticed a couple of seconds delay after the last output despite the document being trivial. Maybe the parsers attempts to connect to the internet? I tried to disable this by settings the features

```py
        parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_external_pes, False)
        parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_validation, False)
```

but to no avail.

How can I convince the DTDHandler to react to the DTD occurring in the document and not connect to the internet?

Comment: You never call the defined method of class, *notationDecl*, that prints output.

Comment: @Parfait That's because I expect the SAX parser to call it once it encounters the `<!DOCTYPE ...>`. The callback is set with the `parser.setDTDHandler(DTDPrinter())` line.

Comment: @Parfait I think I know what you ment: I never called most of the code due a misplaced `!=` when reducing my original code to a minimal example. However, the main issue remains. I updated the question with the new insights gained though.

Comment: *"How can I convince the DTDHandler to react to the DTD occurring in the document and not connect to the internet?"* There is no DTD "in the document". What you have in the document is a DOCTYPE declaration with a reference to the actual DTD available at http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd. To get to the DTD, the parser has to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't receive an answer and couldn't get this to work properly in the past 2 weeks I resorted to violence and simply used a regular expression to extract the information. This is ugly and won't be able to properly process all valid ways to express a DTD but is good enough for my purpose.

```py
import re
DTD_REGEX = re.compile(
    r'<!DOCTYPE\s+(?P<name>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*)\s+PUBLIC\s+"(?P<public_id>.+)"')
dtd_match = DTD_REGEX.match(XML_CODE)
if dtd_match is not None:
    public_id = dtd_match.group('public_id')
    print(public_id)
```